# ¿Cómo crear un singleton para una conexión a MongoDB desde java?

Tags: java, base-de-datos, mongodb, insert

Estoy dando vueltas a un problema pero no logro solucionarlo, estoy creando una aplicación que pueda interactuar con una base de datos SQL y otra de MongoDB.

Para ambas conexiones creo un Singleton de conexión, el problema se encuentra en la conexión con MongoDB y el proceso de insert.
Si lo hago sin crear una clase para ello y creo el clienteMongo desde la clase que representa la ejecución de la aplicación no hay problema.
Espero que podáis ayudarme con esto.

Clase con el Singleton de la conexión a mongoDB

```
public class ConexionMongo {

    private static  MongoClient clienteMongo = null;
    private static DBCollection coleccionCoches;
    private static DB bd=null;


    private ConexionMongo(){
        try{
        clienteMongo= new MongoClient("localhost",27017);
            System.out.println("Se ha creado la conexion con mongoDB.");
        }catch(UnknownHostException ex){
            System.out.println("Error al crear el cliente de conexion a mongo");
        }
    }


    public static MongoClient getConexion(){

        if(clienteMongo == null){
            new ConexionMongo();
        }
        System.out.println("Se ha establecido conexion con la base de datos Mongo");
        return clienteMongo;
    }


    public static DB getBDCoches(){
        if(bd==null){
            bd=clienteMongo.getDB("fabricaCoches");
        }
        System.out.println("Se ha accedido a la base de datos fabricaCoches");

        return bd;
    }

    public static DBCollection getColeccionCoches(){

        if(coleccionCoches==null){

            coleccionCoches=bd.getCollection("coches");
        }

        System.out.println("Se ha accedido a la coleccion de coches");

        return coleccionCoches;
    }

    public void cerrarConexion(){
        try{
            clienteMongo.close();
            System.out.println("La conexion con MongoDB ha sido cerrada");

        }catch(Exception close){
            System.out.println("Error al intentar cerrar la conexion con la bd de Mongo");

        }
    }

    public static void cerrar(){
        if(clienteMongo==null){
            try{
                clienteMongo.close();
            }catch(Exception close){
                System.out.println("Error al intentar cerrar la conexion con la bd de Mongo");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Se ha establecido conexion con la base de datos Mongo");
    }
}
```

Clase que se ejecutará desde el Main

```
public class GestionGuardadoDatos {

private String insertSQL;
Conexion conexion;
ConexionMongo conexionMongo;
private Statement stm;
UtilidadES ues=new UtilidadES(new BufferedReader(new 
InputStreamReader(System.in)),System.out);
ApFabricaCoches aplicacion;
int opc;
BasicDBObject doc;
private DBCollection coleccionCoches;
private DB bd;

private ArrayList<Coche> exportList= ListaCoches.getInstance();


public void exportar(){


    boolean salir=false;
     opc=0;


    do{
        System.out.println("\n Opcion 1: Exportar a BD Oracle.");
        System.out.println(" Opcion 2: Exportar a BD Mongo.\n");
        try {
                        opc =ues.pideInt("Introduzca una opcion");
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        ues.mostrarln("Error toma de datos");
                        }  catch (NumberFormatException nfe){
                            ues.mostrarln("Su opcion no es un numero");
                        }
        switch(opc){

        case 1:
            exportOracle();
            break;

        case 2:
            exportMongo();
            break;
        }


    }while(salir==true);
    }


@SuppressWarnings({ "oracle.jdeveloper.java.semantic-warning", "oracle.jdeveloper.java.insufficient-catch-block" })
public void exportOracle(){


        conexion.getConexion();
        stm = conexion.getStatement();



    for (int i=0;i<ListaCoches.getInstance().size();i++){

      insertSQL="INSERT INTO COCHES.COCHE VALUES ("+ListaCoches.getInstance().get(i).getID_Coche()+",'"+ListaCoches.getInstance().get(i).getMarca()+"','"+ListaCoches.getInstance().get(i).getModelo()+"',"+ListaCoches.getInstance().get(i).getPotencia()+
      ","+ListaCoches.getInstance().get(i).getPlazas()+","+ListaCoches.getInstance().get(i).getPrecio()+")";     


         try {
             stm.addBatch(insertSQL);
             System.out.println("Se ha añadido un insert de coche al batch");

                } catch (SQLException sqle) {
             System.out.println("Algun problema con el addBatch");
               sqle.printStackTrace();
                 try{

                 stm.close();
                 conexion.cerrarConexion();
                     System.out.println("Algun problema con el addBatch");

                 }catch(SQLException cierre){
                     System.out.println("Error al intentar cerrar el objeto sentencia con la BD Oracle.");
                 }
                 System.out.println("Error al intentar añadir una instruccion INSERT al batch.");
             }

    }
    try{
      stm.executeBatch();
        System.out.println("El batch se ha ejecutado correctamente");
    }catch(SQLException errorBatch){
        System.out.println("Error al lanzar el batch de inserccion de datos en la tabla Coches.");           
    }
    }

@SuppressWarnings("oracle.jdeveloper.java.semantic-warning")
public void exportMongo(){

    conexionMongo.getConexion(); 
    conexionMongo.getBDCoches();
    conexionMongo.getColeccionCoches();


        for (int i=0;i<ListaCoches.getInstance().size();i++){

        doc = new BasicDBObject();
          doc.append("_ID",1);

        doc.append("_ID",ListaCoches.getInstance().get(i).getID_Coche());
        doc.append("Marca",ListaCoches.getInstance().get(i).getMarca());
        doc.append("Modelo",ListaCoches.getInstance().get(i).getModelo());
        doc.append("Potencia en CV",ListaCoches.getInstance().get(i).getPotencia());
        doc.append("Plazas",ListaCoches.getInstance().get(i).getPlazas());
        doc.append("Precio final",ListaCoches.getInstance().get(i).getPrecio());
            System.out.println("Debuggin");
            try{
        coleccionCoches.insert(doc);
                System.out.println("Ninguna incidencia al intentar insertar los datos en el documento");

            }catch(Exception v){
                conexionMongo.cerrar();
                System.out.println("No se pudo insertar la informacion en el documento");
            }finally{
                conexionMongo.cerrar();
            }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Que error tienes exactamente?

Comment: El problema se encuentra en el método exporMongo(), los datos no llegan a ninguna coleccion, el cliente mongo se crea ya que he probado a imprimir un listado de las bases de datos. El problema se encuentra a la hora de hacer el insert, no se crea la nueva base de datos("fabricaCoches") y por tanto la coleccion("coleccionCoches"). Creo que el problema se encuentra en la clase conexiónMongo